# Sending multiple requests in any order but no more that 1 request/second

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous

In my c# **wpf** application when a user presses a button I need to send to a server 10-20 requests. They can be sent in an arbitrary order but there has to be at least 10 of them because the server returns the results paginated.

Each client (my c# is a client) has an apy key and **server can only handle 1 request per second per a certain client**, otherwise the server returns an error.

How can send those requests properly? Should I necessarily use async and await? And can I send them in parallel and how? Doesn't async in this case means that they'll be sent in parallel?

And, how can I ensure that only **1 request per second is sent**? I gathered it's not good to mix the threads, which is `Thread.Sleep(1000)` for my case, and async/await.

Answer (score 0):

So, you could create a bunch of tasks that stagger the job by a second each time.

Something like:

```
List<Uri> uris=new List<Uri>(); //fill with uris
var tasks = uris.Select(async (u, i)=>{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i));
    using(var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        return await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(u);
    }
});
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I have to use a third-party non-async library method from their SDK instead of `wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync` which is async. How will the code change?

Comment: Is there no possibility of managing the download yourself and feeding the component the downloaded data? If not, I wonder if async/await is appropriate. It doesn't play all that nicely with synchronous code. How frequently do you having to send out these batches of 10-20 requests?

Comment: no possibility. around once per hour or a half an hour.

Comment: why not to use `Task.Run` for the my syncronous code inside uris.Select ?

Comment: Using `Task.Run` to run synchronous code as if it were asynchronous can often lead to trouble, but if it's only 10-20 requests per half hour, you might be alright.

Comment: I don't understand. You have all means to make synchronous code Task.Run asynchronously. Just add async before Task.Run and await inside the lambda.

Comment: I don't understand. You have all means to make synchronous code Task.Run asynchronously. Just add async before Task.Run and await inside the lambda.